# Increasing the click area of data-icon="delete" in jQuery mobile (having same image size)?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I made a pop up in jQuery Mobile. There is **(X)** button in popup screen. The icon size is perfect, but I need to increase the click area which should be invisible. In other word the icon size remains the same but the click area is increased.

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p943a/

```
$(function(){
  $('#openPopup').click(function(){
    $( "#testCaseId" ).popup( "open" );
  })
})
```

I need to increase the click of this image.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this fiddle, I've made the clickable area red to display the new area. To fix this just change the `background-color` from `red` to `transparent`. The size is completely changeable in CSS. Please ask for help if you need it. I only edited CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/p943a/1/

**CSS**

```
.ui-btn-right::before{
    content:"";
    display:block;
    height:40px;
    width:40px;
    position:absolute;
    background:red;
    left:-5px;
    top:-5px;
}

.ui-btn-right{
   position:relative;
   overflow:visible !important;
}
```

Comment: +1, however, you should be more specific as not to apply those styles to all `.ui-btn-right`. Also, dont play with button's position, `overflow` is enough. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/UK66E/

Comment: @Omar I change some css .I take height and width 100 and 100 but it not make proper circle.http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/UK66E/

Comment: Actually I need big area like 100 ,100 or 150 ,150

Comment: Do you only want it bigger? Sorry I don't understand. If you only want it bigger then will this do? http://jsfiddle.net/UK66E/5/

Comment: @user3665790 to achieve a circle shape, `width`, `height` and `border-radius` should have the same value. Edit: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/sPMSk/